# Customize password length for polymorphic models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have devise model User

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  belongs_to :meta, polymorphic: true
end
```

And two types of users that have a polymorphic association to the User model:

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, as: :meta, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end

class Guest < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, as: :meta, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end
```

**Admin's** password must have minimum 10 symbols length.
**Guest's** password must have minimum 6 symbols length.

How I can set different password length for each model, using devise or any different way?

Comment: Have you tried `validates_length_of :password, :minimum => ` in each model ?

Comment: I tried it, but I got error "NoMethodError in GuestsController". I think, that happened because only model User has field Password and models Admin and Guest don't have it.

Comment: Does your `Guest` and `Admin` models have `password` attribute? If no, I think `Guest` and `Admin` must be inherited from `User` and have their own validations.